# EagerTensor object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to assign a new Value to a TF-Array. Here's my Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.zeros(shape=[5],dtype=tf.float32)
x[1]=0
```

The error message:

```
'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in Tensorflow.

For reference see: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33131

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the value of a TF-Array, you need to set it Variable:

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[5],dtype=tf.float32))
x[1]=0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's 2022 and it still isn't supported. A potential workaround is to convert it to numpy:

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[5],dtype=tf.float32))
x = x.numpy()
x[1]=0
```

It is not ideal but there aren't a lot of options

Comment: Tensors are immutable by design. In graph mode, Python code only provides control structure, which is captured into computation graph. This is just how Tensorflow works. Eager mode, when computations are performed, is the default, but eventually you'll use graph. The best is to use NumPy arrays, but this is not what you can compile into efficient computations later. Also, if you take `Tensor.numpy()`, `Variable` is entirely unrequired. For traceable efficient mutable arrays use `TensorArray` but keep in mind the `ta = ta.update(...)` pattern: each array mutation returns new `TensorArray`.